# MacBook Pro 15 late 2013 yosemite 10.10

Tags: macos, mac, macbook

I'm trying to enable some drivers in my mac and I'm typing this on terminal:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"
```

and press "Enter", but nothing happens..., no password requested...what can I do?

[image]

Comment: Yosemite will not allow unsigned kexts unless you switch that off

Comment: what I have to do exactly?

Comment: [TRIM Enabler, by cindori](http://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/) covers it well

Comment: Please, take a look to this video. This is what I'm trying to do, but I don't know why the Terminal don't ask me to type a password. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPOB9qmPjaE Thank you

Comment: TL:DR… at least précis the steps, no-one is going to watch 12 mins of youtube to help on this.

Comment: I'm sorry...please, you can see the video from 1m:00s to 1m:30s Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to run unsigned kext files, try getting a $99 Apple OS X Developer Certificate and signing them yourself. This will also let you run Macports and Homebrew apps.